# How to compare list with single item in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to compare the list with single item in C#. I am unable to write `if(ListofHorses.Any(x=>x.horseId==model.HorseId))`. The `ListofHorses` holds the count of horses like

`[0] 123
 [1] 124
 [2] 125`
 which I want to compare with single model.horseId which is `120`.

```
 var ListofHorses = horseDetails.HorseList().Where(x => x.AccId == user.AccountID && x.UserId == user.Id).Select(y=>y.HorseId).ToList();
```

Now, I want to compare those 3 values with single item. How to do this?

Comment: Please be a little more specific and reword the question a little, i am having a lot of trouble understand what you actually desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListofHorses` object is collection of `values` not `object`. So you can directly check it as below:

```
ListofHorses.Contains(model.HorseId)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Contains to search for one value in a list.

```
var ListOfHorses = horseDetails.HorseList.Contains("HorseName").Where(blah, blah, blah);
```